# Doctrine2: Map Object with Sub-Entities to Entity without additional table

Tags: php, entity-framework, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm struggling for hours about this one...

I have a `Buddy` object (Entity) which holds (should hold) a `Preference` object. Inside this object I have several collections of sub-objects. For simplicity I'll just explain it with one single sub-object. Let's call it `University`. It's also an entity of its own.

Currently, `Buddy` and `Preference` have a One-to-One association with `Buddy` having a database column `preference_id` and `Preference` just an `id` and nothing else.
`Preference` and `University` have a Many-to-Many association, mapped by Doctrine with a `buddy_preferences_universities` table with `preference_id` and `univeristy_id` columns.

My goal is to establish an association between `Buddy` and `University` keeping the described class hierarchy but without the need of a useless `preferences` table, i.e. I still want to be able to issue `$unis = $buddy->getPreference()->getUniversities` and `$unis` being a `University[]` collection.

So, is it possible to "skip" the `Preference` entity and map the associations directly with the `buddy_id`?

Here's an image of the tables created by Doctrine's `schema-tool`:

[image: DB Tables]

If necessary I can also post the classes and/or XML mapping files.

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for embedding the image! With only 9 reputation I'm not allowed to to that ;-)

Comment: What's the goal of the `Preference` object ? It's a OneToMany relational field with the `Buddy` object ? Can the `Preference` be shared with multiple buddies ? If not, you should use a ManyToMany relation with `Buddy` and `University`, `Country`, and `Interests`.

Comment: The `Preference` is a One-to-One relation with `Buddy`. As I said, I want to be able to access the preferences with `$buddy->getPreference()->getUniversities()` and not `$buddy->getUniversities()`. I want to have a clean `Buddy` object that is not cluttered with a bunch of preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not make your `buddy_preferences` table like this:

```
id: char(36)
university_id: char(36)
country_id: char(36)
interest_id: char(36)
```

Like that you can drop your 3 join tables.

Now you can do `$buddy->getPreference()->getUniversity();`

Comment: That would be easy, but a `Buddy` can have mulitple `University` preferences, therefore the `University[]` Collection :-(

Comment: @Thomas Well in your current db-model it isn't possible either. Or is that what you need a solution for?

Comment: Sure it's possible. One `Buddy` has one `Preference` object (one-to-one relation) and a `Preference` can have multiple `University`s (1:n). Therefore I've got the `buddy_preferences_universities` table.

Answer (score 0):

How about remove the `Preference` entity of your model, then link with a `Many2Many` relation the `Buddy` and the `University` entities.

If you really need to keep the `$buddy->getPreference()->getUniversities()` function call to get all the Universities linked with a Buddy object, instead of `$buddy->getUniversities()`(which sound more logical in my mind, but however..), you can add a function in the `Buddy` class like this :

```
public function getUniversities()
{
    return $this->universities;
}

// Now you'll be able to call $buddy->getPreference()->getUniversities()
public function getPreference()
{
    return $this;
}
```

Althought it's a solution for your needs, I don't really think it's a **good** solution.

Why the `$buddy->getPreference()` is so important if you don't need a `Preference` object ?